# Why doesn't my geocoding-based address verifier output to Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm a mega-beginner (familiar with js from SoloLearn, some Google apps script knowledge from Udemy) trying my hand at setting up an "address verifier" for a dataset that my organization uses. We get address information from people who fill out our forms online and also have interns enter the same info from paper forms that are submitted. This leads to a mess of different address formats being entered into our central Google sheet column.

I'm basically trying to use the geocoder service to take the raw data from that address column (the one in "SpreadsheetApp.getActive"), run it through Google to match it to actual coordinates, then output the correct address using a standard format. I modeled this code from a Stack Exchange thread that I wish I had kept open to link here.

I've debugged this and it seems to "run" just fine, (without error messages), but it doesn't ultimately put out the new addresses. I tried to put a Log in there so that I could see if the geocoder was actually pulling anything into a results object, but I failed with that too. Please help me I am drowning.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
function menuItem1() {
function addrVerify() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var addrRange = sheet.getActiveRange()
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'Addresses': addrRange.value});
function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0)
    {addrRange.value = results[0].formatted_address;;} 
  else alert("Invalid address");
  };
 }
}
```

I was able to put a button to run the function on my sheet's UI, so there's a start. Also, I now know how to do a code fence!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/geocoder#geocode(String)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the example in the above comment I put addresses in column one starting at line two and I used "Address" for column1 header and "Lat" for column2 Header and "Lng" for column3 header.

This code correctly filled in the lat and lng for each address in columns 2 and 3.

```
function addrVerify() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var dsh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = dsh.getRange(2,1,dsh.getLastRow()-1,3);
  var addrA= rg.getValues();

  for(var i=0;i<addrA.length;i++) {
    var resp=Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(addrA[i][0]);
    for(var j=0;j<resp.results.length;j++) {
      var result=resp.results[j];
      addrA[i][1]=result.geometry.location.lat;
      addrA[i][2]=result.geometry.location.lng;
      Logger.log('%s: %s, %s', result.formatted_address, result.geometry.location.lat,result.geometry.location.lng);
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(addrA);
}
```

My spreadsheet looked like this:( only with real addresses)

[image]

Comment: Awesome Cooper, thanks for taking a crack at this! I stored the formatted addresses in column [0] like you did for Lat and Lng: `addrA[i][0]=result.formatted_address;`. Now all of Google's standardized addresses fill out that column. Much more reliable than interns!